# Bcrypt.compare always returns true

Tags: javascript, nestjs, bcrypt

I am using NestJS and Passport to create a simple log in/registration form and I am using bcrypt to see if the password that has been hashed is matching the password that user provides in the login form, but it always returns true

```
    async validateUser(username: string, pass: string): Promise<any> {
        const user = await this.usersService.findOne(username);
        if(user && bcrypt.compare('pass', user.password)) {
            const { password, ...result } = user;
            console.log(pass, user.password)
            return result;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

In the code above, even if I set the argument as a string it will return true and go inside the if statement, which should be false.

Comment: Why is the pass in the compare function a string and not a reference to the variable pass?

Comment: That is just for testing purposes, I wanted to point out that even with a mock string passed in the result in this scenatrio gives back true

Comment: If you're not passing a callback to `bcrypt.compare()`, you're supposed to use `await`, since it returns a promise. And promises are truthy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the compare function of the returns a promise, you need to await it.
Try this:

```
async validateUser(username: string, pass: string): Promise<any> {
        const user = await this.usersService.findOne(username);
        if (!user) return null;
        const pwCheck = await bcrypt.compare('pass', user.password);
        if (!pwCheck) return null;
        const { password, ...result } = user;
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`compare` returns a promise which is truthy

You wanted to use `compareSync`

Answer (score 0):

As `bcrypt.compare` always returns a promise that's why it makes the condition satisfy as true. So, if you want to get response from `bcrypt.compare` you have to use await or.then block. So you can modify your code like this -

```
async validateUser(username: string, pass: string): Promise<any> {
  const user = await this.usersService.findOne(username);
  const isPasswordMatched = await bcrypt.compare('pass', user.password);
  
  if(user && isPasswordMatched) {
      const { password, ...result } = user;
      console.log(pass, user.password)
      return result;
  }

  return null;
}
```